# How to vary function with time in kivy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivymd

such as here is my code :

```
 from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
 from kivymd.uix.button import MDFlatButton
 from kivymd.uix.picker import MDDatePicker
 from kivymd.app import MDApp
 from kivy.lang import Builder
 from kivymd.uix.dialog import MDDialog
 from kivy.core.window import Window
 from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
 from kivy.config import Config

 Config.set('kivy', 'keyboard_mode', 'systemandmulti')

 Window.size = (400, 600)


 class Log_in(Screen, MDApp):
    def dop(self):
       username = self.ids["user"].text
       password = self.ids["passw"].text
       if username == "MD" and password == "kivy":
          self.manager.current = "main"
       else:
          dial = MDDialog(text='Opps Wrong!', background_color=(0.3, 1, 1, 0.3), size_hint=(0.5, 0.5),
                        radius=[20, 7, 20, 7], buttons=[
                MDFlatButton(
                    text="Ok", text_color=self.theme_cls.primary_color, on_release=lambda x: dial.dismiss()
                ), ], )
        dial.open()

  class Main(Screen, MDApp):
     date_y = ObjectProperty()
         def date_se(self):
    y = self.date_y
    try:
        MDDatePicker(self.today_date, y.year, y.month, y.day).open()
    except AttributeError:
        MDDatePicker(self.today_date).open()

def today_date(self, date_obj):
    self.today_date = date_obj
```

As you can see there are 2's screen.

```
class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
pass


kv = Builder.load_file("Wolf.kv")
class Wolf(MDApp):
def build(self):
    self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Yellow"
    self.theme_cls.primary_hue = "900"
    self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"
    return kv


Wolf().run()
```

here is my kivy file(kv):

```
  WindowManager:
  Log_in:
  Main:

  <Log_in>:
      name:"log"
      FloatLayout:
         orientation:"vertical"
         canvas.before:
         Color:
            rgba:rgba('#f2991b')
        Triangle:
            points:[0,self.size[1],self.size[0],self.size[1],0,self.size[1]-(0.4 *self.size[1])]
        Color:
            rgba:rgba('#f2881b')
        Triangle:
            points:[0,self.size[1],self.size[0],self.size[1],self.size[0],self.size[1]-(0.4 *self.size[1])]
    MDIconButton:
        text:'Nxt'
        icon:"account"
        size_hint:0.15,0.15
        pos_hint:{'x':0.43,'y':0.55}
    MDTextField:
        id: user
        hint_text : "Enter your Name"
        helper_text : "Have u forget it?"
        helper_text_mode : "on_focus"
        icon_right : "android"
        size_hint_x :None
        width : '300'
        pos_hint:{'center_x':0.5,'center_y':0.5}
        multiline : False
        foreground_color:0,0,1,1
        on_text_validate: app.on_text_validate_callback(self)
    MDTextField:
        id: passw
        hint_text : "Enter your Password"
        helper_text : "cAsE SeNsItIvE"
        helper_text_mode : "on_focus"
        icon_right : "key"
        size_hint_x :None
        width : '300'
        pos_hint:{'center_x':0.5,'center_y':0.4}
        multiline : False
        password:True
    MDRectangleFlatButton:
        id:btn
        text:"Log in"
        pos_hint:{'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.3}
        on_press:root.dop()
 <Main>:
 name:"main"
    FloatLayout:
       MDIconButton:
          icon:"alarm"
          text:"Hlo"
          on_press:root.date_se()
          size_hint:0.15,0.15
          pos_hint:{'x':0.03,'y':0.8}
```

Now the problem  I am facing is, that I want that after 21 days the Username should be change to "RIOT"
and Password to "zxcvbnm" automatically. As it happen in Most of  antivirus that after certain days they ask for License key. I want only 21 days free Trial of my App to the point.
I think so clock function will be used with if statement but how?
Thnx for help :)

Answer (score 0):

The basic answer is to use Clock.schedule_once to schedule a function that does what you want after the time delay you want.

However, unless you expect your app to be running for 21 days continuously, you'll actually need to do something further to store what time you want the thing to happen, then each time the app starts schedule your function to run at that time.

Comment: could you please provide me a code how to do it, Basically I am Beginner.